# T-sql: Table valued function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have a table with a column `MyFunction` `nvarchar()` that contains the name of a certain table valued function.

There are different functions so the number of columns can differ per function.

1. Is there a way to call the function as a string?

   For example `FunctionA` is a function, Set @MyFunction = 'FunctionA' then call MyFunction('x','y')
2. Is there a way to store the results in a tempTable since we don't know the number of columns up front?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? What real problem are you trying to solve? Functions can't be called by themselves, they have to be part of a statement (eg SELECT).. You *can* store anything to a temp table (especially if you use `SELECT ... INTO ..`) but performance will not be good.

Comment: So you store the name of a table valued function you want to run per row and the output can very per row? This sounds like a horrible architecture to me. You will be fighting this forever.

Comment: Fo #1, it sounds like you are trying to use functions as if they are stored procedures. If you only want to call the function without applying any other statements, use a stored procedure. Either convert the functions to sprocs, or write procedures that only contain `SELECT ... FROM uf_XXX(@param1,...)`

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can do it using dynamic SQL:

   ```
   EXEC sp_executesql N'select * from MyFunction(''x'', ''y'')'
   ```
2. Yes, you can, but you need global temp table:

   ```
   EXEC sp_executesql N'select * into ##test from MyFunction(''x'', ''y'')';
   select * from ##test;
   ```

Hope this works for you

Comment: You need to mention that a ##global temp table will effectively limit concurrency to 1.